# Angular - How to resolve ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in Excel donwload

Tags: angular, excel, asp.net-core

I have an application that queries, search filter data, and also exports to excel. I use ASP.NET Core-6 Web API for the backend and Angular-15 for the frontend. The backend has only one endpoint that performs both query search filter and excel export. But there is conditional (if) statement there.

When I tried it at the backend, I have this:

[image: swagger display]

Then when I click on `Download file` the file got downloaded successfully.

However, at the Angular frontend, everything works fine except the export to excel. When I click the onExportToExcel() button, I got this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at g (FileSaver.min.js:1:1481)
    at Object.next (merchants.component.ts:195:15)
```

and it points at:

```
saveAs(response.body, fileName);
```

Then:

```
console.log(response);
```

gives

```
Blob {size: 3245, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}
size
: 
3245
type
: 
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Blob
arrayBuffer
: 
ƒ arrayBuffer()
length
: 
0
name
: 
"arrayBuffer"
arguments
:
```

Don't forget that the backend controller code here has already dealt with the filename. The issue is with the frontend

Backend:

Controller:

GetAllMerchantAsync:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(ApiRoutes.Admin.GetAllMerchants)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllMerchantAsync([FromQuery] PagingFilter filter, [FromQuery] bool exportToExcel = false)
{
    if (exportToExcel)
    {
        var response = await _merchantService.ExportAllMerchantToExcelAsync(filter);

        if (response.Successful)
        {
            var fileBytes = response.Data;
            var fileName = $"MerchantReports_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";

            return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(response.StatusCode, response.Message);
        }
    }
    var result = await _merchantService.GetAllMerchantAsync(filter);
    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

Frontend:

Angular:

MerchantService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, of } from 'rxjs';
import {
  IPageResult,
  IResponse,
  IMerchantList,
  IPagingFilter,
} from 'src/app/features/admin/models/merchant/merchant-list.model';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MerchantService {
  baseUrl = environment.baseHost;
  token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' }).set(
      'Authorization',
      `Bearer ${this.token}`
    ),
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}


  getAllMerchantsFilter(
    filter: IPagingFilter
  ): Observable<IPageResult<IMerchantList[]>> {
    const params = this.buildParams(filter);
    return this.http
      .get<IResponse<IPageResult<IMerchantList[]>>>(
        `${this.baseUrl}/merchants/all-merchants`,
        { params }
      )
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));
  }

  private buildParams(filter: IPagingFilter): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (filter.searchQuery) {
      params = params.append('searchQuery', filter.searchQuery);
    }
    if (filter.sortBy) {
      params = params.append('sortBy', filter.sortBy);
      params = params.append(
        'isSortAscending',
        filter.isSortAscending.toString()
      );
    }
    if (filter.startDate && filter.endDate) {
      params = params.append('startDate', filter.startDate.toISOString());
      params = params.append('endDate', filter.endDate.toISOString());
    }
    params = params.append('pageNumber', filter.pageNumber.toString());
    params = params.append('pageSize', filter.pageSize.toString());
    if (filter.exportToExcel) {
      params = params.append('exportToExcel', 'true');
    }
    return params;
  }
}

  exportMerchantToExcel(filter: IPagingFilter): Observable<any> {
    const params = this.buildParams(filter);
    const options = { params: params, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' };

    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/merchants/all-merchants`, options);
  }
```

Merchant.Component.ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  TemplateRef,
  OnInit,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter,
} from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  AbstractControlOptions,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { MerchantService } from 'src/app/features/admin/services/merchant.service';
import {
  IPageResult,
  IResponse,
  IMerchantList,
  IPagingFilter,
} from 'src/app/features/admin/models/merchant/merchant-list.model';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-merchants',
  templateUrl: './merchants.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./merchants.component.scss'],
})
export class MerchantsComponent implements OnInit {
  bsModalRef?: BsModalRef;
  merchantList: any;
  isLoading = false;
  isSubmitted = false;
  event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  allMerchantList!: IMerchantList[];
  pageResult!: IPageResult<IMerchantList[]>;
  filter: IPagingFilter = {
    searchQuery: '',
    sortBy: '',
    isSortAscending: true,
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    exportToExcel: false,
  };
  minStartDate!: Date;
  minEndDate!: Date;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private merchantService: MerchantService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private config: NgSelectConfig,
    private orderPipe: OrderPipe
  ) {
    this.config.notFoundText = 'Custom not found';
    this.config.appendTo = 'body';
    this.config.bindValue = 'value';
    this.minStartDate = new Date();
    this.minEndDate = new Date();
    this.minStartDate.setFullYear(this.minStartDate.getFullYear() - 60);
    this.minEndDate.setDate(this.minEndDate.getDate());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userStatus;
    this.userRole;
    this.userAdmin;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  loadAllMerchants() {
    this.merchantService
      .getAllMerchantsFilter(this.filter)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.pageResult = result;
        this.allMerchantList = result.pageItems;
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  onPageChanged(pageNumber: number) {
    this.filter.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  onPageSizeChanged(selectedValue: string) {
    this.filter.pageSize = parseInt(selectedValue, 10);
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  onSearch() {
    this.filter.pageNumber = 1;
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  onSort(sortBy: string) {
    if (this.filter.sortBy === sortBy) {
      this.filter.isSortAscending = !this.filter.isSortAscending;
    } else {
      this.filter.sortBy = sortBy;
      this.filter.isSortAscending = true;
    }
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }

  onDateRangeSelected(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    this.filter.startDate = startDate;
    this.filter.endDate = endDate;
    this.loadAllMerchants();
  }


  onExportToExcel(): void {
    this.filter.exportToExcel = true;

    this.merchantService.exportMerchantToExcel(this.filter).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        const fileName = response.fileName; // Use the fileName from the backend
        saveAs(response.body, fileName);
        this.filter.exportToExcel = false; // Reset the exportToExcel flag
      },
      (error) => {
        this.toastr.error('Failed to export data to Excel.');
        this.filter.exportToExcel = false; // Reset the exportToExcel flag
      }
    );
  }
  onClose() {
    this.bsModalRef?.hide();
  }
}
```

Merchant.Component.html:

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-12">
        <div class="card card-danger">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ search }}</h3>
            <div class="card-tools">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-tool"
                data-card-widget="collapse"
              >
                <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"
                        ><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i
                      ></span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
                      class="form-control"
                      bsDatepicker
                      [minDate]="minStartDate"
                      [(ngModel)]="filter.startDate"
                      [bsConfig]="{
                        isAnimated: true,
                        dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                        returnFocusToInput: true,
                        showClearButton: true,
                        clearPosition: 'right'
                      }"
                      (change)="onSearch()"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"
                        ><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i
                      ></span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
                      class="form-control"
                      bsDatepicker
                      [minDate]="minEndDate"
                      [(ngModel)]="filter.endDate"
                      [bsConfig]="{
                        isAnimated: true,
                        dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                        returnFocusToInput: true,
                        showClearButton: true,
                        clearPosition: 'right'
                      }"
                      (change)="onSearch()"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Searsh By: "
                      class="form-control"
                      id="searchInput"
                      [(ngModel)]="filter.searchQuery"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        type="button"
                        (click)="onSearch()"
                      >
                        Search
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 text-right">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-success"
                  title="Export Excel Data"
                  (click)="onExportToExcel()"
                >
                  <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export
                  to Excel
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-12">
        <div class="card card-danger">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ pageTitle }} List</h3>
            <div class="card-tools">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-tool"
                data-card-widget="collapse"
              >
                <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                  <th (click)="onSort('merchantName')">
                    Merchant Name <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span
                    ><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
                  </th>
                  <th (click)="onSort('accountNumber')">
                    Account Number <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span
                    ><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
                  </th>
                  <th (click)="onSort('mobileNumber')">
                    Mobile Number <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span
                    ><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
                  </th>
                  <th (click)="onSort('createdBy')">
                    Created By <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span
                    ><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
                  </th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody *ngIf="allMerchantList != undefined">
                <tr
                  *ngFor="
                    let row of allMerchantList
                      | paginate
                        : {
                            itemsPerPage: filter.pageSize,
                            currentPage: filter.pageNumber,
                            totalItems: pageResult.totalRecord
                          }
                      | orderBy
                        : filter.sortBy
                        : filter.isSortAscending
                        : false;
                    let i = index
                  "
                >
                  <td style="width: 80px">{{ i + 1 }}.</td>
                  <td>{{ row?.merchantName || "N/A" }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row?.accountNumber || "N/A" }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row?.user?.mobileNumber || "N/A" }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row?.user?.createdBy || "N/A" }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <span
                      class="badge"
                      [ngClass]="
                        row?.merchantStatus == '1' ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-danger'
                      "
                      >{{ row.merchantStatus | toStatus }}</span
                    >
                  </td>
                  <td>

                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="allMerchantList.length == 0">
                  <td colspan="7" class="text-center">
                    <span class="align-center">No Data Found!</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer clearfix">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <pagination-controls
                  previousLabel="Prev"
                  nextLabel="Next"
                  [responsive]="true"
                  (pageChange)="onPageChanged($event)"
                ></pagination-controls>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                Items Per Page:
                <select
                  [(ngModel)]="filter.pageSize"
                  #pageSizeSelect
                  (change)="onPageSizeChanged(pageSizeSelect.value)"
                >
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="50">50</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz with your reproducable error code?

Answer (score 0):

The saveAs library checking the Blob when make new link. Part of sorcecode:

```
function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
    var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'
```

May be it's crashes at `blob.name`

Recommendations:

`"const fileName = response.fileName; // Use the fileName from the backend"` does not contain "fileName". It's contains headers and there you can get the 'content-disposition' header.

And one thing u do know. Make setup for you asp.net application like this:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
                );
```

of course you can make your own header -  .WithExposedHeaders("Content-FileName").

And now on Angular side you will able to get headers:

```
response.headers.get('content-disposition');
```

or

```
response.headers.get('content-filename');
```